# How secure is a firebase app layer firewall based on auth token claims?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, network-security

I'd like to restrict certain requests to whitelisted IPs.

The implementation seems easy enough; just store the user's IP as a custom claim
that can be checked against a whitelist using security rules.

How secure is a Firebase app layer firewall based on auth token claims?

Alternatively, should the problem be tackled by restricting access to certain oauth providers (Azure AD, Auth0) that provide conditional access controls such as IP and device whitelisting?

**References**

- [Context Object Properties in Rules](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/context-object)
- [Conditional Access: Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-grant)
- [Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Comment: Custom claims can only be set by users with administrator-level access to the Firebase project. So if a certain claim is set to a value, you can be certain it was set by an account with those access permissions. But it's hard to say more about how secure an implementation is going to be, because that depends almost solely on the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Frank. On the wider point, what are the implications of having the firewall in the app vs the authentication provider? My instincts are that this behaviour relies on security expertise that properly sits with the auth layer, and I wonder if firebase should bring this expertise into security rules, or at least provide guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting Frank's comment as Wiki for visibility.

Custom claims can only be set by users with administrator-level access to the Firebase project. So if a certain claim is set to a value, you can be certain it was set by an account with those access permissions. But it's hard to say more about how secure an implementation is going to be, because that depends almost solely on the implementation.

Comment: I've responded to Frank's comment against the original question.